# tx_news: Detail/single view not accessable

Tags: typo3, tx-news

We're using News system on a 7.6 and in this particular system we have a bug when it comes to single view.
If you click on link in list view, the detail page opens, you can see the header image, but the news article isn't loaded, instead the CE is is displaying an error message:

> Oops, an error occurred! Code: 201609301037026977c150

Can anyone advise?

Comment: You should first read How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

This TS-Snippets will enable error message without more Details for developers.